# How to create folder using a controller function on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how can i create a folder using a controller function?

(Routes and all are good, but don't know how to make the folder)

I have a simple form for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label name="title">Slug:</label>
        <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
</form>
```

Route in web.php:

```
Route::post('projects/postUpload', ['uses' => 'AdminController@storeProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.store']);
```

I want to put to the folder the same name of the slug.

```
public function storeProject()
    {
        return ;
    }
```

Know how to do it?

Comment: use mkdir(path,mode,recursive,context) function

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use `Storage`:

```
Storage::makeDirectory($directory);
```

It will create a new folder on specified disk (local storage, AWS etc).

If you want to create a new folder on the local disk, you can use `File` facade:

```
File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775);
```

Comment: Now i will try it. If doesn't work i will edit this comment, if works i edit the question.

Comment: I have to put: File::makeDirectory('/assets/img/projects/hola', 0775,true); and i get the error: mkdir() permission denied. i'm using nginx

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer it's not related to Laravel. You can use `chmod` command to fix permissions, but do not do that, it's a terrible idea. Use `storage` directory to store uploaded stuff. Or use services like AWS. But do not use `assets` directory. If you want to have access to uploaded files, you need to create a symbilic link. Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: the problem is that i need to create a folder when i create a new project. And then, in the form will be 2 pics and i need store it in the folder.. a bit confusing for me, i will try to make a directory changing permision and then use storage.